# React-native switch selector effect transition page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-animated

I'm trying to implement a SwitchSelector, but I'm having a problem with the page change.
I would like a transition to occur between the page when the user changes it with the movement inside it, from the right to the left and left to the right.
Link: https://snack.expo.io/Sk5GY7Je7
Can someone give me a hand?